# C++ Deriving from interface with nested class

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface

I'm writing code to deal with objects of type "Foo". A foo is a type of container, and to provide efficient and abstracted access to its elements, it provides a nested class of type `Element`. An `Element` wraps the position of the object in the container.

Now, there may be different implementations of a "Foo", so I'm writing an abstract base class `FooInterface` to give them a common interface. The problem is that each implementation may need to define its own `Element` type. For example, one implementation may keep its data in a vector such that its `Element` wraps a vector iterator, while another implementation contains a list, and its `Element` wraps a list iterator.

I have cooked up a solution that works using void pointers. Essentially, the base class defines an `Element` class that wraps a void pointer. The different implementations of `FooInterface` can cast the void pointer into whatever type they use to represent an element. For the moment, ignore the memory leaks:

```
class FooInterface
{
    public:
    class Element {
        void* payload;
        public:
        Element(void* payload) : payload(payload) {}
        void* getPayload() const { return payload; } 
    };

    virtual void say_element(Element) = 0;
    virtual Element getElement() = 0;
};


class FooOne : public FooInterface
{
    public:
    virtual void say_element(Element element)
    {
        std::cout << "FooOne says: " << 
            * (int *) element.getPayload() << "." << std::endl;
    }

    virtual Element getElement()
    {
        return Element(new int(42));
    }
};


class FooTwo : public FooInterface
{
    public:
    virtual void say_element(Element element)
    {
        std::cout << "FooTwo says: " << 
            * (std::string*) element.getPayload() << "." << std::endl;
    }

    virtual Element getElement()
    {
        return Element(new std::string("This is a test"));
    }
};


void say(FooInterface& foo)
{
    FooInterface::Element el = foo.getElement();
    foo.say_element(el);
}


int main()
{

    FooOne foo_one;
    FooTwo foo_two;

    say(foo_one);
    say(foo_two);

    return 0;
}
```

While this works, it seems like there must be a better way. My understanding is that void pointers should be avoided, if at all possible. So, is this the best way to accomplish this?

### *Edit:*

I did an admittedly poor job of describing just what I'm trying to do in this post. Nevertheless, the answers were helpful to get me thinking, and I've devised what I think is a decent solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21630680/1231929).

Comment: You didn't describe the problem you need to solve. The idea sounds pretty terrible, but it's impossible to tell whether it has merit without context.

Comment: Obviously here it would be a huge mistake to do `FooOne foo1; FooTwo foo2; foo2.say_element(foo1.getElement())`.  Is it possible you could have a `FooThree` where it's possible and sometimes necessary to have `foo3.say_element(foo2.getElement())`?  Or would it be good to force the various element classes to all have different types?

Comment: _'My understanding is that void pointers should be avoided'_ If you have an **interface**, you usually don't need to back up on `void` pointers?!?

Answer (score 1):

You could make `FooInterface` a template and pass whatever `Element` should store as it a template parameter:

```
template <typename Payload>
class FooInterface
{
    public:
    class Element {
        Payload payload;
        public:
        Element(Payload payload) : payload(payload) {}
        Payload getPayload() const { return payload; } 
    };

    virtual void say_element(Element) = 0;
    virtual Element getElement() = 0;
};
```

Your subclasses will then have to pass the appropriate template parameter to the super class:

```
class FooOne : public FooInterface<int>
{
    public:
    virtual void say_element(Element element)
    {
        std::cout << "FooOne says: " << 
            element.getPayload() << "." << std::endl;
    }

    virtual Element getElement()
    {
        return Element(42);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to have each container consistently expose its element type as `FooXXX::Element`, then you could templetize the `FooInterface` and add a typedef for `Element`:

```
template<class elem>
class FooInterface {
public:
    typedef elem Element;
    /*... */
};

class FooOneElement {
    /*... */
};

class FooOne : public FooInterface<FooOneElement> {
    /*... */
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the different types of datatype that are going to be used, why not declare corresponding variables in derived class and then use them? There won't be a need of void* in base class. Also I think, you can avoid using virtual keyword in all derived classes, instead, you can specify virtual before the function to be used in base class.

Or else you could use templates to define same function with one parameter of different types.
Refer this, its really useful

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5351/Simulation-of-Virtual-Function-with-Template

Thanking You

Answer (score 0):

You want a `container, [...] to provide efficient and abstracted access to its elements`. This is a trade-off between a generic (virtual) and
efficient (template) implementation. Due to abstraction you will loose efficiency (compared to standard containers). Putting the access and iteration of elements into the elements of the container is (in my view) plain wrong design. In addition your solution is (as mentioned) far from being type safe.

A type safe solution might be:

```
// Library
// =======

#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename Element>
class BasicElements
{
    public:
    typedef Element element_type;

    protected:
    struct Implementation {
        virtual element_type& get() = 0;

        virtual bool first() = 0;
        virtual bool next() = 0;
        virtual bool last() = 0;
        virtual void end_of_elements() = 0;

        virtual void insert(const element_type&) = 0;
    };

    template <typename Container>
    struct BidirectionalImplementation : Implementation {
        typedef Container container_type;
        typedef typename container_type::value_type value_type;
        typedef typename container_type::iterator iterator;
        container_type elements;
        iterator position;

        BidirectionalImplementation()
        :   position(elements.begin())
        {}

        virtual bool first() {
            position = elements.begin();
            return (position != elements.end());
        }

        virtual bool next() {
            if(position != elements.end())
                return (++position != elements.end());
            return false;
        }

        virtual bool last() {
            position = elements.end();
            if(position != elements.begin()) {
                --position;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        virtual void end_of_elements() {
            position = elements.end();
        }
    };

    template <typename Container>
    struct SequentialImplementation : BidirectionalImplementation<Container> {
        private:
        typedef BidirectionalImplementation<Container> Base;

        public:
        typedef typename Base::container_type container_type;
        typedef typename Base::value_type value_type;
        typedef typename Base::iterator iterator;

        public:
        virtual element_type& get() {
            if(this->position == this->elements.end())
                throw std::out_of_range("Position");
            return *this->position;
        }

        virtual void insert(const element_type& e) {
            this->position = this->elements.insert(this->position, e);
            ++this->position;
        }
    };

    template <typename Container>
    struct MapImplementation : BidirectionalImplementation<Container> {
        private:
        typedef BidirectionalImplementation<Container> Base;

        public:
        typedef typename Base::container_type container_type;
        typedef typename Base::value_type value_type;
        typedef typename Base::iterator iterator;

        public:
        virtual element_type& get() {
            if(this->position == this->elements.end())
                throw std::out_of_range("Position");
            return this->position->second;
        }

        virtual void insert(const element_type& e) {
            this->position = this->elements.insert(this->position, value_type(e.key(), e));
        }
    };

    template <typename Other>
    BasicElements(std::shared_ptr<Other> p)
    :   m_self(std::static_pointer_cast<Implementation>(p))
    {}

    public:
    element_type& get() { return m_self->get(); }
    const element_type& get() const { return m_self->get(); }

    bool first() const { return m_self->first(); }
    bool next() const { return m_self->next(); }
    bool last() const { return m_self->last(); }
    void end_of_elements() const { m_self->end_of_elements(); }

    void insert(const element_type& e) { m_self->insert(e); };

    private:
    std::shared_ptr<Implementation> m_self;
};

/// PRECONDITION The container fulfills (a subset of) the requirements
///              for a standard (bidirectional) sequence container.
template <typename Container>
class SequentialElements : public BasicElements<typename Container::value_type>
{
    private:
    typedef BasicElements<typename Container::value_type> Base;

    protected:
    typedef typename Base::template SequentialImplementation<Container> Implementation;

    public:
    SequentialElements()
    :   Base(std::make_shared<Implementation>())
    {}
};

/// PRECONDITION The container fulfills (a subset of) the requirements
///              for a standard (bidirectional) associative container.
///              The mapped type of the container has a member K key() const,
///              where K is convertable to the key_type of the container.
template <typename Container>
class MapElements : public BasicElements<typename Container::mapped_type>
{
    private:
    typedef BasicElements<typename Container::mapped_type> Base;

    protected:
    typedef typename Base::template MapImplementation<Container> Implementation;

    public:
    MapElements()
    :   Base(std::make_shared<Implementation>())
    {}
};


// Test
// ====

#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

class Element
{
    public:
    Element(int value)
    :   m_key(value), m_value(value)
    {}
    Element(int key, int value)
    :   m_key(key), m_value(value)
    {}

    int key() const { return m_key; }
    const int& value() const { return m_value; }
    int& value() { return m_value; }

    private:
    int m_key;
    int m_value;
};

inline bool operator < (const Element& a, const Element& b) {
    return a.key() < b.key();
}


int main() {
    typedef SequentialElements< std::vector<Element> > vector_elements;
    typedef SequentialElements< std::list<Element> > list_elements;
    typedef MapElements< std::map<int, Element> > map_elements;

    vector_elements v;
    v.insert(Element(2));
    v.insert(Element(1));
    v.insert(Element(0));

    list_elements l;
    map_elements m;

    if(v.first()) {
        do {
            l.insert(v.get());
            m.insert(v.get().value());
        }
        while(v.next());
    }

    const char* ContainerName[] = {
        "Vector",
        "List",
        "Map"
    };

    typedef std::vector<BasicElements<Element>> container_collection;
    container_collection collection;
    collection.push_back(v);
    collection.push_back(l);
    collection.push_back(m);
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < collection.size(); ++i) {
        const BasicElements<Element>& elements = collection[i];
        std::cout << ContainerName[i] << "\n";
        if(elements.first()) {
            do {
                std::cout << elements.get().value() << '\n';
            }
            while(elements.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the long and detailed answer. I did a poor job describing my problem, unfortunately. In regards to having the access of elements of a container implemented in the elements themselves, I probably wasn't very clear, either. Say I have a `Graph` that internally stores nodes in a vector. If `Graph::Node` simply wraps the index of the node, I can support `O(1)` lookup. But another implementation may store the nodes in a list, and so `Graph::Node` may wrap a pointer to the node object. So, no, the elements aren't doing the accessing, but they do wrap an index or iterator of some type.