# C++: Does this pattern have a name, and can it be improved?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, design-patterns, inheritance

### The motivation

Let's say I'm writing a `Tree` class. I will represent nodes of the tree by a `Tree::Node` class. Methods of the class might return `Tree::Node` objects and take them as arguments, such as a method which gets the parent of a node: `Node getParent(Node)`.

I'll also want a `SpecialTree` class. `SpecialTree` should extend the interface of a `Tree` and be usable anywhere a `Tree` is.

Behind the scenes, `Tree` and `SpecialTree` might have totally different implementations. For example, I might use a library's `GraphA` class to implement a `Tree`, so that `Tree::Node` is a thin wrapper or a typedef for a `GraphA::Node`. On the other hand, `SpecialTree` might be implemented in terms of a `GraphB` object, and a `Tree::Node` wraps a `GraphB::Node`.

I'll later have functions which deal with trees, like a depth-first search function. This function should accept both `Tree` and `SpecialTree` objects interchangeably.

### The pattern

I will use a templated interface class to define the interface for a tree and a special tree. The template argument will be the implementation class. For example:

```
template <typename Implementation>
class TreeInterface
{
    public:
    typedef typename Implementation::Node Node;

    virtual Node addNode() = 0;
    virtual Node getParent(Node) = 0;

};

class TreeImplementation
{
    GraphA graph;   

    public:
    typedef GraphA::Node Node;

    Node addNode() { return graph.addNode(); }
    Node getParent() { // ...return the parent... }

};

class Tree : public TreeInterface<TreeImplementation>
{
    TreeImplementation* impl;

    public:
    Tree() : impl(new TreeImplementation);
    ~Tree() { delete impl; }

    virtual Node addNode() { return impl->addNode(); }
    virtual Node getParent() { return impl->getParent(); }

};
```

I could then derive `SpecialTreeInterface` from `TreeInterface`:

```
template <typename Implementation>
class SpecialTreeInterface : public TreeInterface<Implementation>
{
    virtual void specialTreeFunction() = 0;
};
```

And define `SpecialTree` and `SpecialTreeImplementation` analogously to `Tree` and `TreeImplementation`.

My depth-first search function might look like this:

```
template <typename T>
void depthFirstSearch(TreeInterface<T>& tree);
```

and since `SpecialTree` derives from `TreeInterface`, this will work for `Tree` objects and `SpecialTree` objects.

### Alternatives

An alternative is to rely more heavily on templates so that `SpecialTree` isn't a descendent of `TreeInterface` in the type hierarchy at all. In this case, my DFS function will look like `template <typename T> depthFirstSearch(T& tree)`. This also throws out the rigidly defined interface describing exactly what methods a `Tree` or its descendents should have. Since a `SpecialTree` should *always* act like a `Tree`, but provide some additional methods, I like the use of an interface.

Instead of the `TreeInterface` template parameter being the implementation, I could make it take a "representation" class that defines what a `Node` looks like (it will also have to define what an `Arc` looks like, and so on). But since I'll potentially need one of these for each of the implementations, I think I'd like to keep this together with the implementation class itself.

What do I gain by using this pattern? Mostly, a looser coupling. If I'd like to change the implementation behind `Tree`, `SpecialTree` doesn't mind at all because it only inherits the interface.

### The questions

So, does this pattern have a name? I'm using the handle-body pattern by storing a pointer to `ContourTreeImplementation` in `ContourTree`. But what about the approach of having a template-ized interface? Does this have a name?

Is there a better way to do this? It does seem that I am repeating myself a lot, and writing a lot of boilerplate code, but those nested `Node` classes give me trouble. If `Tree::Node` and `SpecialTree::Node` had reasonably similar implementations, I could define a `NodeInterface` interface for a `Node` in `TreeInterface`, and override the implementation of the node class in `Tree` and `SpecialTree`. But as it is, I can't guarantee that this is true. `Tree::Node` may wrap a `GraphA::Node`, and `SpecialTree::Node` may wrap an integer. So this method won't quite work, but it seems like there might still be room for improvement. Any thoughts?

Comment: An implementation of the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)?

Comment: Your basic idea is pretty similar to [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) but you seem to have something more going on.

Comment: @user2079303 I was playing around with the CRTP, and you're right, it's very similar. What prevented the CRTP from working was that the derived class would be defining the `Node`, while the base class would have `typedef Impl::Node Node;`. At compile time, however, `Impl` is incomplete, so the code won't compile.

Comment: It's best described as some mixup of composite, strategy and CRT patterns.

Comment: I think you can still create a nodeinterface class, for example specialtree::node could simply consist of an integer and a pointer to the tree itself. Unfortunately you would have to dynamically allocate node objects and return suitable smart pointers for the interface to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a mixture of the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) and the [Pimpl idiom](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom).

In the CRTP, we derive `Tree` from `TreeInterface<Tree>`; in your code you're deriving `Tree` from `TreeInterface<TreeImplementation>`. So it's also as @ElliottFrisch said: it's an application of the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). Certain parts of the code care that `Tree` conforms to `TreeInterface`, while certain other parts care about the fact that it uses the particular *strategy* `TreeImplementation`.

> Is there a better way to do this? It does seem that I am repeating myself a lot

Well, it depends what your runtime requirements are. When I look at your code, the thing that jumps out at me is that you're using `virtual` methods — slooooow! And your class hierarchy looks like this:

```
Tree is a child of
  TreeInterface<TreeImplementation>

SpecialTree is a child of
  TreeInterface<SpecialTreeImplementation>
```

Notice that the fact that `TreeInterface<X>::addNode()` happens to be `virtual` has **absolutely no bearing on whether** `TreeInterface<Y>::addNode()` is virtual!  So making those methods `virtual` doesn't gain us any runtime polymorphism; I can't write a function that takes an arbitrary instance of `TreeInterfaceBase`, because we haven't *got* a single `TreeInterfaceBase`. All we've got is a bag of unrelated base classes `TreeInterface<T>`.

So, why do those `virtual` methods exist? Aha. You're using `virtual` to pass information from the derived class back up to the parent: the child can "see" its parent via inheritance, and the parent can "see" the child via `virtual`. This is the problem that is usually solved via CRTP.

So, if we used CRTP (and thus didn't need the `virtual` stuff anymore), we'd have just this:

```
template <typename Parent>
struct TreeInterface {
    using Node = typename Parent::Node;
    Node addNode() { return static_cast<Parent*>(this)->addNode(); }
    Node getParent(Node n) const { return static_cast<Parent*>(this)->getParent(n); }
};

struct ATree : public TreeInterface<ATree> {
    GraphA graph;
    typedef GraphA::Node Node;

    Node addNode() { return graph.addNode(); }
    Node getParent(Node n) const { // ...return the parent... }
};

struct BTree : public TreeInterface<BTree> {
    GraphB graph;
    typedef GraphB::Node Node;

    Node addNode() { return graph.addNode(); }
    Node getParent(Node n) const { // ...return the parent... }
};

template <typename Implementation>
void depthFirstSearch(TreeInterface<Implementation>& tree);
```

At this point someone would probably remark that we don't need the ugly pointer-casting CRTP at all and we could just write

```
struct ATree {
    GraphA graph;
    typedef GraphA::Node Node;

    Node addNode() { return graph.addNode(); }
    Node getParent(Node n) const { // ...return the parent... }
};

struct BTree {
    GraphB graph;
    typedef GraphB::Node Node;

    Node addNode() { return graph.addNode(); }
    Node getParent(Node n) const { // ...return the parent... }
};

template <typename Tree>
void depthFirstSearch(Tree& tree);
```

and personally I would agree with them.

Okay, you're concerned that then there's no way of ensuring through the typesystem that the `T` the caller passes to `depthFirstSearch` actually conforms to `TreeInterface`. Well, I think the most C++11-ish way of enforcing that restriction would be with `static_assert`. For example:

```
template<typename Tree>
constexpr bool conforms_to_TreeInterface() {
    using Node = typename Tree::Node;  // we'd better have a Node typedef
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<Tree>().addNode()), Node>::value, "addNode() has the wrong type");
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<Tree>().getParent(std::declval<Node>())), Node>::value, "getParent() has the wrong type");
    return true;
}

template <typename T>
void depthFirstSearch(T& tree)
{
    static_assert(conforms_to_TreeInterface<T>(), "T must conform to our defined TreeInterface");
    ...
}
```

Notice that my `conforms_to_TreeInterface<T>()` will actually static-assert-fail if `T` doesn't conform; it will never actually return `false`. You could equally well make it return `true` or `false` and then hit the `static_assert` in `depthFirstSearch()`.

Anyway, that's how I'd approach the problem. Notice that my entire post was motivated by the desire to get rid of those inefficient and confusing `virtual`s — someone else might latch onto a different aspect of the problem and give a totally different answer.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I ended up using templates, as you suggested. For better or for worse, I'm trying to avoid assuming that a C++11-supporting compiler is available, and so I've used concept-checking code similar to what is used in the Boost Concept Check Library. Overall, I really like the approach of defining concept template classes then implementing concrete versions of them.